# Manifest and supported devices showed in android market

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is there a tool out there which could test my android manifest to see which devices are supported by the android market with given settings? I hope that there is some way other than uploading every test to android market.

I need to find out why some small screen devices are not supported, but I have not yet found the reason.

I currently support the following screens and I suppose that `android:smallScreens` should let Samsung Galaxy Mini with Android 2.3 install my app, but it does not.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

edit: current permissions and features:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" required="false" />
```

I think I have to remove some of these- I have garbage here which is not needed anymore. 
Will digg into it tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: Which values you have in manifest for `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` and which "Android project build target" you have in the project's properties?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8" and no targetSdkVersion set (should I?). 

Used Google API's platform 2.2 as build target.

Comment: Could there be some very specific privileges you app uses and those phones not? Like not having camera or certain sensors?

Comment: That is what made me ask this question at first place- I don't know. I have to manually check this out. Would be much easier to "validate" it somehow. But I suppose I eventually have to make it manual.

Comment: Which privileges your app has?

Comment: Added permissions and features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a tool out there which could test my android manifest to see which devices are supported by the android market with given settings?

No, simply because Google is the only firm with a (fairly) complete catalog of all Android devices and their capabilities.

If somebody created an independent database that could be crowdsourced (e.g., maybe something on Fluidinfo), then independent tools could use it.

With respect to your specific problem, after screen size, the next most likely candidate would be permissions implying certain required features that the device lacks.

Comment: Something that I thought. Thank you all anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that Galaxy Mini isn't compatible with CAMERA permission. It's all about

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

this feature is added by default with

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Here you can find more info about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html under "Future-proofing".
If you add CAMERA permission with `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`
autofocus will not be added and it should be now compatible with your app.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Certain permissions such as CAMERA or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION imply other feature settings. I found that making my implied features optional increased the compatibility of my application from 1100 devices to over 2000.

The particular sticking points for me were implied camera autofocus and network based location implied by the camera and coarse location permissions. To overcome this I used:

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
```

These are the settings I used in my game Zombie Splatter (lite) in the Play store. It took me 8 upload attempts and three days to get the permissions I needed. Google really ought to make a compatibility tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the same as mine. Samsung Galaxy Mini is not compatible with "android.permission.CAMERA" - see answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8822791/385264