# How to find out what hardware requirements my Android application has?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

hope my question doesn't sound much awkward. I have Android application which runs fine on many Android phones. However, I've just found out that on my friend's Samsung Galaxy Mini (S5570) it won't even find my app in Android Market. When I use direct link to my app in Market, it says that the App is not compatible with the phone. I have no idea why ??

I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>
```

I am not aware of anything what should disable my app from beeing compatible with Samsung Galaxy Mini or maybe other phone I don't know about yet.

Can anybody help me with this strange problem ?

**EDIT:**

I've checked in Android Market Developer Console and there is more or different set of permissions than I have in my manifest file:

```
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.location.network
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.camera.autofocus
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

I think that `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` might probably the reason for my app not showing in Android Market for certain phones. Anybody has idea how to get rid of this requirement I don't want to have for my app ?

Comment: Do you have any native code/library, which may have some dependency on the ARM version?

Comment: I am not aware of such. My application is actually HTML5 using PhoneGap 1.0. I am using ZXing plugin for barcode reading. But I don't think this would have any dependency on ARM version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Samsumg Galaxy Mini is not compatible with "android.permission.CAMERA"

Comment: Wow, that is very disrupting. But Samsung Galaxy Mini has indeed camera, so where is problem ? Any thoughts ? Any workarounds ? The only thing that comes to my mind is to remove the camera from requirements, right ? But that would render my app useless, because it needs camera for some functionality.

Comment: Yes I know, and I dont know why. What I did was add a link to download the apk directly.

Comment: add this
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" required="false"/>

The android.permission.camera implicit adds android.hardwre.camera.autofocus.

Answer (score 2):

Please see my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007883/app-is-incompatible-with-all-devices-after-publishing-to-the-market-but-same-was).

In short, run your apk through **aapt dump badging**, which will tell you exactly which features will be used by the market to determine the availability to devices. Then adjust your manifest file accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the android:required="false" to disable it from the store filter.