# How do i put compatiable screens for nexus 6

Tags: android, manifest

I am developing an android app, which only want to support in mobile phone devices. But compatible screen in manifest is only support up to xhdpi then how I put compatible xxxhdpi in android manifest. 
Is any way to do it.

Comment: what do you consider mobile devices? a tablet is a mobile device, please be more specific

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only

Comment: @tyczj but in developer forum it says that "Note: This attribute currently does not accept xxhdpi as a valid value, but you can instead specify 480 as the value, which is the approximate threshold for xhdpi screens."

Comment: then how can i add xxxhdpi when xxhdpi is not there

Comment: why do you need to add compatible screen in manifest?

Comment: because the app only want to support  in mobile phone devices

Answer (score 0):

`android:xlargeScreens` doesn't mean that it supports `xhpdi`. It means it supports `extra large screen form-factors`, as per API docs:

> Indicates whether the application supports extra large screen form-factors. An xlarge screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "large" screen, such as a tablet (or something larger) and may require special care on the application's part to make good use of it, though it may rely on resizing by the system to fill the screen

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge

Specific configurations for `xxxhdpi` has to be done via `/res` sub directories, e.g. `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/some_drawable.png`. Not via `Manifest`.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: thank you for yor answer. But actually i asked about how to show my app in xxxhdpi resolution in google paly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for us in the manifest for all new devices:

```
<compatible-screens>
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="420" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="480" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="640" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
```