# Google Play App for Mobile phones only

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play, android-manifest

I want to upload my app only for mobile phones for that i added the following code inside my manifest 
`

```
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
</compatible-screens>`
```

But few devices like nexus5x, Nexus6 and Nexus6p are not supported for my app when i uploaded my app at Google play store.Can some one tell me what did i wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only

Comment: first you have to define what a `mobile phone` is. How does it differ from not a mobile phone? What should it have to make it a mobile phone?

Comment: @VladMatvienko sorry i can't understand what you want to explain or ask from me ?

Comment: how you recognize if it is a mobile phone, or not? What is the difference? GSM module? screen size? Or what?