# can not simulate some android devices

Tags: android

I am new to app developing and I have this problem with android emulator… 
when I use virtual devices with screen size 5.7" or smaller every thing is ok..however,  when I change to simulate with devices with bigger screens 6" or higher…  the app not running…
I don't know which part is making this problem…  so I don't know which part of the code I show u… 
any help is highly appreciated…

Comment: post Your log detail

Comment: The Best Option is, use `Droid4x windows` ,`nox windows` Software for Android Emulator...

Comment: thx for the suggestion, still having the same problem when I installed nox software..  any help plz

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the AndroidManifest? You might made the app to support only small devices by mistake. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only) this might be the mistake.

Comment: thank you... I was away from my computer for few days...I have tried with supporting the four screen sizes as the following:                                                                         
  <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>                                                         
 also I have tried without this ... still the same problem