# How to exclude every device except from phones in google console

Tags: android, google-console-developer

I'm publishing my first game, which is only meant for phones. I'm in google console > device catalog, and I would like to exclude every device except from phones. Is there a way how to do it, without having to manually exclude every device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restrict app to Android phones only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only). I believe including `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />` is the cleanest option.

Comment: Also, if you only include screenshots for the phone sizes, from memory, your app will only be available for that format. I think you may even get a warning of the limited distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do in mainfest with use of  because in Play store we
 don't have any option to select the option like phone,tablet ,watch etc but still . We can 
 restrict the app installation to certain device by when you upload your APK at Market see 
 All Applications > select your application > APK > Supported devices | Excluded devices.