# How to customize the main store listing in the google console?

Tags: react-native, google-play

I have question is their way to customize the main store listing? I want to remove the table requirements because the app want to apply on the phone devices not in the tablet devices.

I read some articles or post that I need to go this section in the google console.

Reach and devices -> Device Catalog

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your app to Phones only from the app `manifest` for more on this see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230554/how-to-restrict-app-to-android-phones-only).

for Google Play store listing, you can add 1 screenshot for each tablet size using a phone screen shot, in that way you will only target phones.

the problem with "Device Catalog" approach that you will need to do this every time new devices were added to google play console which is very hard to do.

Comment: table screenshot is required? is there no way to remove that requirements?